# Empty Bibliography after changing style to chem-acs

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a problem using Biblatex/Biber. First I used:

`\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`

Everything worked fine. Then, I wanted to change the style to chem-acs. This gave me the warning: Empty bibliography.

Tried changing the style to authortitle, this didn't give me the error. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Info: MacOSX version 10.11.5, Texmaker version 4.5

Comment: Try deleting the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bcf`, `.bbl`) and recompile from scratch. If the error keeps coming back, please try and provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Have a look at the `.log` and `.blg` files.

Comment: Thank you! I only deleted the `.bcf`and `.bbl` files and then compiled it again. Deleting all three files solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a subtle one: it's caused by the change of sorting order between the standard styles and the `chem-acs` one. The standard styles do `sorting = nty`, the ACS one `sorting = none`. This causes some issues with data left in the `.aux` file, which is where the error comes from. (You can see the issue by simply adding `sorting = none` after a LaTeX/Biber/LaTeX cycle with no style explicitly loaded, as that does `sorting = nty` implicitly.)

As noted in a comment, deleting the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` files (or simply ignoring the error, getting to the end of the run and re-running Biber) clears the issue. However, this should at the very least give a better error message: I've [logged in the `biblatex` issue tracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/524).